# Joint space trajectory control (MoveIt)

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a question about MoveIt and its capabilities: I have a robot which only can be controlled by joint poses (6DoF). Well If I'm trying to use MoveIt it generates the joint poses and velocities too. My problem is that I only can control the robot with joint poses, so I cannot send it velocity parameters. If I only send the joint poses and want the robot to move the end effector down, it doesn't follow a straight line. Is there a way to make MoveIt generate the joint poses without velocities, but with the result of a good end-effector moving?  Like go from A to B through N steps. 1. step: Only move joint 1 by 0.02 rad, step 2. joint 1 by 0.04rad AND joint 1. by 0.001 rad and so on, but with have the end-effector move in a straight line?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227277/joint-space-trajectory-control-(moveit)/) by [Joska213](https://answers.ros.org/users/26025/joska213/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt by default actually only plans in joint space. I believe you want to generate Cartesian trajectories.

For that you can use [moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::computeCartesianPath(..)](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#ad6b02d15000d5b17c89b15a0f744b47c). There is also a GUI interface for that: [moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin) (it's really a ui, not a planning plugin), but that might be a bit hard to setup.

Alternatively you could interpolate between poses yourself and use something like [descartes](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes) to turn it into a joint space trajectory.

If you really just want a chopping stage for MoveIt's output, you could configure one of the ROS-Industrial [trajectory_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_trajectory_filters) as a State Adapter and configure the step size appropriately.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joska213](https://answers.ros.org/users/26025/joska213/) on 2016-02-22**:
Thanks for the answer! It's ok tha MoveIt generate plans in joint space, but I cannot utilize velocity information of the given points. I need ponts without timing and velocity informations so I could send them to the robot and it should keep the end-effector in a straight line.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2016-07-15**:
To crop the velocity and timing information, you could just configure a relay node that deletes them. But are you sure, you cannot just ignore this information?